# Parse.com REST API - reverse inverse pointer query lookup

Tags: parse-platform

I have the following two classes

```
Game 
  objectId
  player1
  player2

Round
  objectId
  game (pointer to Game.objectId)
```

Each game can have many rounds which is why I have used a poitner (all the parse docs seem to say pointers for one to many or realtion for many to many)

At the moment I am successfully running a query on the Round class and i'm using the include option to pull the Game data within the round results.  This is all great and works perfectly..

However, I have now realised that a Game may exist without any Rounds (initially at least). Because of this, I am trying to re-wrtie my query from the Game class perspective but whatever I try I am unable to 'include' the Rounds associated with the Game.

I though maybe I should have a 'rounds' pointer column in Game class that points to a gameObjectId column in 'Round' but it wont let me add it and errors.  I think this is because pointer needs to point to the objectId of the class you are pointing to - this wont work for me as that would the Round objectId.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Maybe I need a realation but it isn't a many -many  relationship.  I've read as much as i can find in the parse docs about relationships, etc but it still not clear to me.

Im from a sql background which is why i can't seem to grasp the problem - it should be straight forward but im clearly missing something.

Hope somebody can advise on how to achieve this.  Im happy to tweak my schema if needs be.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pointers getting all objects on both sides of the relationship requires two API requests:

```
PFQuery *gameQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
[gameQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"some_id" block:^(PFObject *game, NSError *error) {
    PFQuery *roundQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Round"];
    [roundQuery whereKey:@"game" equalTo:game];
    [roundQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *rounds, NSError *error) {

    }];
}];
```

Instead of pointers, you may want to use an array (assuming one game will not have more than 100 rounds, otherwise it wouldn't be efficient):

```
Game
objectId
player1
player2
rounds (round array)

Round
objectId
```

Then you can use `include` again (as you do it with pointers) and get games with its rounds:

```
PFQuery *gameQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
[gameQuery includeKey:@"rounds"];
[gameQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"some_id" block:^(PFObject *game, NSError *error) {

}];
```